# Serving contain to sub domains from an MVC / IIS web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cors

I am hosting the blog for my site on tumblr:

blog.withoomph.com

I have modified the theme on the blog and I want to use my own fonts that I use on our main site. I am trying to get the fonts from:

beta.withoomph.com

However, when the page tries to fetch the fonts I am getting a CORS error. This only started hapenning recently, as they use to be fetched with no issues.

Is there a way I can set either IIS or my MVC app to service these fonts to sub domains?

**Edit**

Sorry, I should know better than that. Here is some more information:

This is the CSS to fetch the urls:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'avantgarde';
    src: url('http://beta.withoomph.com/content/fonts/avant_garde.eot');
    src: url('http://beta.withoomph.com/content/fonts/avant_garde.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('http://beta.withoomph.com/content/fonts/avant_garde.woff') format('woff'),
         url('http://beta.withoomph.com/content/fonts/avant_garde.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('http://beta.withoomph.com/content/fonts/avant_garde.svg#avantgarde_bk_btdemi') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

And this is the error in dev console when it tries to fetch the fonts:

> Font from origin 'http://beta.withoomph.com' has been blocked from
>   loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://blog.withoomph.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Comment: Can we see some code please?

Comment: Yeah sorry, was a poor quesiton that, hopefully the extra information makes things clearer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For security reasons browsers prohibit calls to resources residing outside the current origin so you have to enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing. add this to `web.config`.

```
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

For more information see [this link](http://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html).

Comment: Fantastic stuff, just what I was looking for. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Please note that allowing `*` means you're accepting request from anyone and everyone, potentially opening yourself up to Cross site scripting attacks.